# "being" usage instead of "which is" at the end of a sentence

Tags: phrases, gerunds, clauses

I saw a sentence while reading a book in which the following is written.

> “The `NOW` function is sometimes called a nondeterministic function **, which is** a fancy way of saying that the resulting data returned from
>   this function is different every time it is called”
>
> Excerpt From: Shields, Walter. “SQL QuickStart Guide: The Simplified
>   Beginner's Guide to Managing, Analyzing, and Manipulating Data With
>   SQL.” Apple Books.

Can be "which is" replaced by "being" here as being like,

“The `NOW` function is sometimes called a nondeterministic function **, being** a fancy way of saying that the resulting data returned from
 this function is different every time it is called”

Can be the conversion(alternative version) applied always?

Comment: No, "being..." does not sound right there.

Comment: I think *being* attaches more naturally to the subject of the main verb (here *function*).